# How to match in a group each time the data between { } without match certain data also between { } with regex and flutter?

Tags: regex, flutter

I have this List of string in input

```
>>> Text("key1:[{"title":"Date: J4 (2020-09-04)\n\nDistance:  5\nDurée:
>>> 5\nPoids: 5 d\nObservations:  blabla\n","completed":false},
>>> {"title":"Date: J4 (2020-09-04)\n\nDistance: 4\nDurée: 3\nPoids:
>>> 4\nObservations: bla\n","completed":false}]"),

>>> Text("key2:[{"title":"Date: J5 (2020-09-05)\n\nDistance:  5\nDurée:
>>> 5\nPoids: 5 d\nObservations:  blablabla\n","completed":false},
>>> {"title":"Date: J4 (2020-09-07)\n\nDistance: 4\nDurée: 3\nPoids:
>>> 4\nObservations: blablabla\n","completed":false}]"),
```

Currently I success to match in one group all data in key1 with this regex

```
(?<=Text\("key1:\[{)(.*)(?=})
```

---

```
(?<=Text\("key1:\[{) is my positive lookbehind, I start capture after Text("key1:[{ 
(.*) is to match all characters
(?=}) is to stop when I have a }
```

But I search to have a different group like that

> group1 "title":"Date: J4 (2020-09-04)\n\nDistance:  5\nDurée:
> 5\nPoids: 5 d\nObservations:  blabla\n","completed":false
>
> group2 "title":"Date: J4 (2020-09-04)\n\nDistance: 4\nDurée: 3\nPoids:
> 4\nObservations: bla\n","completed":false

Important : I need to match only all {data} in `key1` and make different match group for each {data}

I need a mix like that, but currently doesn't work

```
(?<=Text\("key1:\[{){(.*?)}(?=})
```

with this     `(?<=Text\("key1:\[{)(.*)(?=})` I can select only data's in Key1

with this `{(.*?)}` I can match all data between `{ }`

How mix this two regex ?

Edit: I found this one who work your help

```
(?<=Text\("key1:\[[^\][]*?){(.*?)}(?=[^\][]*])
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The expected output is like my example with group1 and group2 but can have more group if user save more data. If I have {data1},{data2},{data3} I expect to have group1=data1 group2=data2 group3=data3

Comment: But your sencond group of data is not prefixed with `Text("key1"`, cant you just match the {...} with `\{.*?\}`

Comment: My problem with this, is that I need to select specific prefix to not capture other data who can also be formated with { }

Comment: You may post your regex as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have working regex: `(?<=Text\("key1:\[{).+?(?=})`

EDIT:

If you want to match everything between curly brackets, you can use this regex: `{(.*?)}`

Comment: Yes it's ok for the first {data1} but currently I can have some data like that {data1},{data2},{data3} and I search to match all this data in a different group like that group1=data1 group2=data2 group3=data3

Comment: If all groups are between "{" and "}" you can use this one: `{(.*?)}`

Comment: My problem with this, is that I need to select specific prefix to not capture other data who can also be formated with { }

Comment: I have 2 solution working sepatly but can't mix like that ... (?<=Text\("key1:\[{){(.*?)}(?=})

Comment: I found with this one (?<=Text\("key1:\[[^\][]*?){(.*?)}(?=[^\][]*])

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to do with this regex

```
(?<=Text\("key1:\[[^\][]*?){(.*?)}(?=[^\][]*])
```